# expected value of an exponential function of an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Could anyone please assist with this problem:

> Given $Y$ has an exponential distribution with mean $5$, and $h(y) = exp(-Y)$, 
>   find $\mathbb{E}[h(y)]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of $Y$ is given by 
$$
f_{Y}(y)=\frac{1}{5}e^{-y/5};\quad (y>0)
$$
whence
$$
Ee^{-Y}=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{5}e^{-y/5} e^{-y}\,dy
$$
which you can compute.